# Disable app installation but allow upgrades on iOS device

Tags: ios, app-store, mdm

We would like to be able to set up iOS devices in such a way that users are not allowed to install new apps but are allowed to upgrade existing apps. Ideally this would be implemented as an MDM profile. I've looked at allowAppInstallation, but according to the documentation, this disables both installation and upgrade. These devices will all be assigned a common Apple ID account, and users will not in general have access to the password for this account. This gets us close to what we want. The user will be prompted for a password on new installations but not on upgrades to free apps. We need to be able to lock to devices to the assigned Apple ID, though. I've seen some references indicating that there's a way to do this, but haven't found the appropriate setting or MDM key.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a perfect solution for you. However, here are some thoughts.

- I have never heard of a way to lock Apple ID. In the case, if you will find it, please post here, it would be useful.
- Just plain MDM won't help you too much for multiple reasons. As you pointed out, it disables both install and upgrade. Also, a user can delete MDM profile (including all restrictions associated with it).
- I would recommend to take a look at Apple Configurator. It allows you to prepare Supervised devices. I believe it gives you couple of additional tricks (may be you will have some idea how to use it as part of jigsaw puzzle).
- There are several undocumented keys for Managed Settings (could be managed through MDM). Mainly they enable/disable all kinds of logging, but may be some of these keys could be useful for you. Usual disclaimer: taking into that it's not documented, it could go away any time.

**Selfish advertising**

In the case, if you need a solution (rather than a software development approach), please take a look at our [SpydrSafe product](http://www.spydrsafe.com/). We can blacklist apps (including AppStore). This way a user won't be able to install new apps. My profile has my email address, if you want to discuss this.